# Groovy class to extract json returns null

Tags: groovy

I'm in the process of adding to the Library of reusable functions. I've added a class to extract JSON from the SOAP response but I get a NULL in return. The script below works fine, the issue is when I add this to a class.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.*
responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStepName").getPropertyValue("response");
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent);
log.info (slurperresponse.items[0].id);
//Write response to property
def addResponseID = slurperresponse.items[0].id
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("ScheduleId", addResponseID)
```

The Class:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.*;
class GetXmlNode
{
def log
def context
def testRunner
def responseSOAXmlStep
def resultValue
def responseNodePath
def responseContent = "mycontent"
def slurperresponse = "myresponse"
def storeProperty = "id"
// Class constructor with same case as Class name
def GetXmlNode(logIn,contextIn,testRunnerIn)
    {
    this.log = logIn
    this.context = contextIn
    this.responseSOAXmlStep = responseSOAXmlStep
    this.responseNodePath = responseNodePath
    this.testRunner = testRunnerIn
    this.storeProperty = storeProperty
    }

    def execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath,storeProperty)
{
    responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(responseSOAXmlStep).getPropertyValue("response");
        slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent);
    resultValue = (slurperresponse.responseNodePath);
    log.info("Node value: " +  resultValue );
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue(storeProperty, resultValue );

        return responseSOAXmlStep
}

}
 context.setProperty( "GetXmlNode", new GetXmlNode( log, context, testRunner) )
```

The Calling script:

```
// get a reference to the library TestSuite
library = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject().getWorkspace().getProjectByName("Library")
library = library.getTestSuiteByName("Library");

// find the module within the library 
module = library.testCases["Library"].testSteps["GetXMLNodeValueByJSON"]

// initialise the library; which places an instance of Example in the context
module.run(testRunner, context)

// get the instance of example from the context.
def GetXmlNode = context.GetXmlNode

// run the method, with parameter
 log.info "GetXmlNode.execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath,storeProperty) = " +  GetXmlNode.execute("TestStepName","items[0].id","JsonId")
```

The Response:
Wed Nov 19 14:00:58 CAT 2014:INFO:Node value: null

Updated Code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.*;
class GetXmlNode
{
def log
def context
def testRunner
def responseSOAXmlStep
def resultValue
def responseNodePath = "items[0].id"
def responseContent = ""
def slurperresponse = ""
def storeProperty = ""
// Class constructor with same case as Class name
def GetXmlNode(logIn,contextIn,testRunnerIn)
    {
    this.log = logIn
    this.context = contextIn
    this.responseSOAXmlStep = responseSOAXmlStep
    this.responseNodePath = responseNodePath
    this.testRunner = testRunnerIn
    this.storeProperty = storeProperty
    }

    def execute(responseSOAXmlStep,responseNodePath,storeProperty)
{
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
    responseContent =     testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(responseSOAXmlStep).getProperty("Response").getValue();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent);
//          log.info (slurperresponse.responseNodePath);
//      def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( responseSOAXmlStep+"#ResponseAsXml" );
    resultValue = "resultValue " + jsonSlurper[responseNodePath];
    log.info("Node value: " +  resultValue );
    log.info("Response Node Path: " +responseNodePath)
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue(storeProperty, resultValue );


        return responseSOAXmlStep
}

}
context.setProperty( "GetXmlNode", new GetXmlNode( log, context, testRunner) )
```

Response:
Tue Dec 02 10:16:33 CAT 2014:INFO:Node value: resultValue null

Comment: Can you provide a short, complete example demonstrating what happens if you add it to a class. What are we supposed to look at if the code you show us works fine?

Comment: Hi, I've added the class in question. Please help

Comment: It seems there's nothing wrong with adding the method to a class. The issue is in the way i'm declaring a variable to store the root node e.g. items[0]. Does anybody know how I could use a variable to parse the rootnode?

Comment: Hi guys I'm still struggling with this, can someone suggest at least an amendment or something that will help?